# WPF DataGrid bind to properties of class inside List

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, data-binding

I am trying to bind a `DataGrid` to a `List` so it automatically updates when the list does.

In my xaml.cs:

```
private DataStorage dataStorage = new DataStorage();
```

xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="DropFilesDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colFileName" Binding="{Binding fileName}" Header="File Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colFileType" Binding="{Binding fileType}" Header="File Type" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colFileLocation" Binding="{Binding fileLocation}" Header="File Location" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In `DataStorage` class:

```
public List<File> listOfFiles = new List<File>();
```

and the File class:

```
private string fileName { get; set; }
private long fileSize { get; set; }
private string fileImage { get; set; }
private string fileLocation { get; set; }
private string fileType { get; set; }
```

I add new files to the list via:

```
foreach (string fileDropped in files)
{
    File file = new File(fileDropped);
    dataStorage.AddFileToList(file);
}
```

The list is getting filled with these file objects and the properties are not null.

My issue is getting the `DataGridView` to update with it?

My error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'fileName' property not found on 'object' ''File' (HashCode=1820782)'. BindingExpression:Path=fileName; DataItem='File' (HashCode=1820782); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'fileType' property not found on 'object' ''File' (HashCode=1820782)'. BindingExpression:Path=fileType; DataItem='File' (HashCode=1820782); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'fileLocation' property not found on 'object' ''File' (HashCode=1820782)'. BindingExpression:Path=fileLocation; DataItem='File' (HashCode=1820782); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection<File>` instead of `List<File>`And also use `public` member of class `File`.

```
public ObservableCollection<File> listOfFiles = new ObservableCollection<File>();
```

AND

```
  public string fileName { get; set; }
  public long fileSize { get; set; }
  public string fileImage { get; set; }
  public string fileLocation { get; set; }
  public string fileType { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you changed member of class 'File' as a public?